# AutoCompleteBox drop-down disconnects from input when drag window

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, wpf-controls, drop-down-menu

Has anyone seen a bug where you are using the WPF AutoCompleteBox control and while the drop-down is displayed you drag the window and the drop-down stays put while the entire window moves and now the drop-down is completely disconnected from the input field?

Does anyone know which event I could turn the drop-down off in this case?  Or how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the Popup control strikes again. I don't use AutoCompleteBox but I think it has an IsDropDownOpened property. You could set that to false when the window is moved. Maybe not the most elegant solution but it should workaround your issue.

Comment: You got me on the correct path!!!  Just set IsDropDownOpen to false on the window's LocationChanged event and it cleans it up....Thanks!  Now if I could just get the up/down arrow keys to work per my other question I would be set: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440984/autocompletecombobox-arrow-up-arrow-down-keys-to-scroll-list